# Specifying condition with NIntegrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, conditional, boundary-conditions

I have an integral

$$
P_{\frac12 + \mathrm i\mu}(\eta) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \cosh(\pi\mu) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\mu\tau)}{\sqrt{\cosh\tau + \eta}} \mathrm d\tau, \quad \eta \geq 1, \quad \mu \geq 0,
$$

where I want to enforce that $$\forall  \mu \geq 0,  P_{\frac12 + \mathrm i\mu}(\eta = 1) = 1 $$ holds.

My code for evaluating this integral is

```
int1[η_, μ_] := (Sqrt[2]/π) Cosh[π μ] NIntegrate[ Cos[μ τ]/Sqrt[Cosh[τ] + η], 
                                                  {τ, 0, Infinity}];
```

But not sure how to enforce this condition.

Comment: Rami, I think the values you get for high eta might be affected by a large error. I get warnings about lack of convergence when I try to execute your code. Your integrand is (horrendously) oscillatory for large values of eta. `NIntegrate` does detect the oscillatory nature of the integrand on an infinite one-dimensional domain and automatically selects the `"DoubleExponentialOscillatory"` method, but that might still not work, or the parameters of that method might need further tweaking in your case.

Comment: @MarcoB I totally agree. It is highly oscillatory. I thought perhaps there could be a way around this. Tricky I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most reliable approach would be symbolic and it appears we can get this integral in a symbolic form if we suplement `Integrate` by appropriate assumptions. We define the integral with `Set` (i.e. `=`) to avoid repeating the same calculation every time:

```
int1[η_, μ_] = Sqrt[2]/π Cosh[π μ] Integrate[ Cos[μ τ]/Sqrt[Cosh[τ] + η],
                                               {τ, 0, Infinity}, 
                                             Assumptions -> μ >= 0 && η >= 1];
```

and we can demonstrate exactly that the formula for `η == 1` doesn't depend on `μ`:

```
  FullSimplify[ int1[1, μ]]
```

> ```
>  1
> ```

The analytical formula for `int1` reads in terms of the `AppellF1` function:

```
TraditionalForm[ int1[η, μ]]
```

[image]

Moreover we can sketch plots of this integral as a function of `μ` for various values of `η`, first defining the `PlotLabel`:

```
st=Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)] + i\\\ \\[Mu]\)]\)(\[Eta])", Thick, 24]
```

and now (it takes a bit)

```
Plot[Evaluate @ 
       Table[ int1[η, μ], {η, {1, 101/100, 21/20, 7/6, 8/6, 2, 5}}], 
     {μ, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
      PlotLabel -> st, PlotLegends -> Table["η=" <> ToString[N @ η], 
                                            {η, {1, 101/100, 21/20, 7/6, 8/6, 2, 5}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just an extended comment:

If you plot the solution

```
Plot3D[int1[eta, mu] , {eta, 1, 3}, {mu, 0, 3},MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> 1, AxesLabel -> Automatic,AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

with the meshline `int1[eta, mu]==1` it looks like there is no solution `int1[1, mu]==1` 
detectable in the plotted parameter range!

Comment: What do you mean by `nt1`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `int1[…]`

Comment: Why don't you change it?

Answer (score -1):

Try to put instead $\;\mu=m^2$ and $\;\eta=e^2$, and fix $m$ and $e$ as reals:

```
int1[e_Real, m_Real] := (Sqrt[2]/π) Cosh[π m^2]*
   NIntegrate[
    Cos[m^2 τ]/Sqrt[(Cosh[τ] + e^2)], {τ, 0, Infinity}];
```

Do not forget in such a case to give the corresponding parameters with the decimal point.For example:

```
int1[0.01, 0.2]

(* 1.18151 *)

int1[-0.01, 0.2]

(* 1.18151  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But this doesn't fix the integral to be 1 when mu is large.

Comment: This is beyond the question you have initially asked. I only answered, how to make sure that your parameters are positive. I am not responsible for the results of the integration.